# To achieve Grand total for the retrieved column

Tags: visualforce

Can any one help me out .How to get the subtotals and grand totals added for the fields like quantity,Amount in  a visual force page PDF Format.Any Suggestion PLZ.

I have a custom visual force page created on "Quote "Object in a PDF format where the data gets displayed .Writing Wrapper class i have achieved the data of opportunity forecast details.Now i would Like to get

1) To Filter the Product Name ,With Quantity and Amount for Every Quarter.

2)To Achieve the Subtotals and Grandtotals for the Quantity and Amount .

VF CODE :

```
<table class="bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Opportunity Name</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">PartNumbers</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quantity</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Price</td>
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Amount</td>
               <!-- <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Quarter</td>-->
                <!--<td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Month</td>--> 
               <!-- <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Actual Price</td>-->
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Year</td>
               <!-- <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">Date</td> --> 
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">MonthText</td> 
                <!--<td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">ForecastDate</td>-->
                <td class="header-table-heading" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">ForecastName</td> 
                <td rowspan="0" class="header-table-heading">Grand<br/>Total </td> 
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <apex:repeat value="{!disp_list}" var="opf">
            <tr>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Opportunity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Product}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quantity}"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Price }"/></td>
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Amount }"/></td>
               <!-- <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Quarter }"/></td>-->
                <!--<td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Month }"/></td>-->
               <!-- <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.Actual_Price }"/></td>-->
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Year }"/></td>
              <!--  <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_date }"/></td> -->  
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.gmod_Month_Text }"/></td> 
               <!-- <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.Forecast_Date }"/></td>-->
                <td class="header-table-data"><apex:outputText value="{!opf.Name }"/></td>
             </tr>
            </apex:repeat> 
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Apex Code :

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

       public Competitor__c com{get;set;}

       public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist{get;set;}

       public Id qId {get;set;}

       Public string all{get;set;}

//Declare a wrapper class  

       public class Wrapperclass{

 //custom wrapper datatype  

       Public string Name{get;set;}  
       Public string AccountType{get;set;}  
       Public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
       Public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
       Public string Probability{get;set;}  
       Public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
       Public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

       Public string Segment{get;set;}  
       Public string Application{get;set;}  
       Public string Persona{get;set;}  
       Public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

       Public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
       Public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

       Public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
       Public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
       Public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
       Public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
       Public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
       Public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
       Public string Other_information{get;set;}  

       Public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
       Public string Volume{get;set;} 
       Public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

       Public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
       Public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
       Public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
       Public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
       Public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
       Public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
       Public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}



       Public wrapperClass(){} 

  }

       Public QuoteContentController(){}

       Public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

       qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');

    }

        Integer subtotalofquantity{get;set;}

        Integer subtotalofamount{get;set;}

       Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{

       subtotalofquantity = 0;

       subtotalofamount = 0;

     // Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list(){
    //define constructor to instantiate the wrapper data type 

       disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

     //Query all the list 

     list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,QuoteNumber,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,Quote.Opportunity.id, 
                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                    from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];

    // list<QuoteLineItem> qli =[Select QuoteId , PricebookEntry.Product2.Name ,Unitprice ,End_Customer_Price__c ,Quantity , TotalPrice from QuoteLineItem where QuoteId =:qId ];

   //  list<Account> a = [Select id ,Name ,Main_Customers_of_Account__c ,Bridgelux_Competition_at_Account__c,Servicing_Region__c ,
                     // Annual_LED_Revenue__c,Annual_Purchases_of_LED_Sources_SAM__c ,Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB__c from Account where account.id =:qId ];

   //  list<Competitor__c>  com = [Select id ,Part_Number__c,Product_Series__c,Price_Offered__c,Volume__c,Date_Price_is_Valid__c from Competitor__c ]  ; 

     Opportunity opp =[select id , Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), probability, AccSegment__c from Opportunity where opportunity.Id =:q[0].opportunity.id];

     list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.id,gmod__Product__c,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c , gmod__Month__c,    gmod__date__c,  gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c ,gmod__Year__c ,gmod__Month_Text__c ,Forecast_Date__c,gmod__Product__r.Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null and gmod__opportunity__r.id =:opp.id order by gmod__Month__c asc limit 6]; 

   // list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist=[ SELECT  id,gmod__product__r.name,gmod__Quantity__c,createdby.name , gmod__opportunity__r.name ,gmod__Amount__c,GROUPING(gmod__Quantity__c) grpQty, GROUPING(gmod__Amount__c) grpAmt ,COUNT(id) oppfc from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c GROUP BY CUBE(gmod__Quantity__c, gmod__Amount__c) ORDER BY GROUPING(gmod__Quantity__c), GROUPING(gmod__Amount__c) ];

  // Executes in DC 
  // [SELECT  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c,COUNT(id) cnt FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null GROUP BY  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c];
//Executes in DC
 //[SELECT  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c,sum(gmod__Price__c) gmod__Price__c ,SUm(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c,Sum(gmod__Quantity__c)gmod__Qunatity__c,COUNT(id) Quantity FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c GROUP BY  gmod__product__r.name ,gmod__opportunity__c];

       //Iterate through each list to extract the values and add it to the custom wrapper data type  

        for (Quote qt :q){
             System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
             System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());

            for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++){

            subtotalofquantity += integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);

            subtotalofamount  += integer.valueOf(opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c);

            //for(gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c op: opflist ){

                    //system.debug('Opp id++ '+Quote.Opportunity.id);
                    //if(qt.Quote.Opportunity.id == op.opportunity__r.id){

                                        //Instantiating the wrapper SObject 

                                        wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();


                    //Assigning the wrapper variables from the SObject Fields in the database. 

                 w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;

                 w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

                 w.gmod_Price=opflist[i].gmod__Price__c;

                 w.Name =opflist[i].Name;

                 w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;

                 w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;

                 w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;

                 w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;

                 w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;

                 w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;

                 w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;

                 w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c;
                              //Adding everthing to the List  


                            // w.name =qt.name;

                              disp_list.add(w);

                              // return disp_list;  
                    //}         
       }
     }
   }  
 } //End of Class
```

Comment: please provide us what you have tried so far so that we can help you further.

Comment: @DKSalesforce Lerner :I have updated the code.Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @nikkey **Public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{** looks like you are incorrectly doing some work here.  The final '{' is sort of just hanging there enclosing your other stuff.  The **get;set;** already covers your **disp_list** variable.  You need to extract this and put it in a method or something similar somewhere.

Comment: @dphil:Can u plz help me out where i need to extract and put in a method.